# Issue in reading records from hive bucket

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, sample

I have created a hive table with 4 buckets..
I can read the data from nth bucket ..

For example..

```
Select * from collection tablesample(bucket 1 out of 4 on loan_id)
```

But how to retrieve the data from 2nd and 3rd bucket..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try UNION ALL:

```
Select * from collection tablesample(bucket 2 out of 4 on loan_id)
UNION ALL
Select * from collection tablesample(bucket 3 out of 4 on loan_id)
```